# Howto install FreeFileSync on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am attempting to install FreeFileSync to Ubunto 16.04. I am following the instructions on

https://launchpad.net/freefilesync

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs
```

seems to run OK, The site
http://www.dlecan.com/archives/56-How-to-install-FreeFileSync-on-Ubuntu-PPA-Edited.html
not found
http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/freefilesync gives the same advices.

However, command

```
sudo apt-get install freefilesync
```

results in `package freefilesync not found`

What do I wrong?

Comment: Formely not, but now I did. No difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **Xenial** is not yet supported by your [launchpad repo](https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ubuntu/ffs).

You can do the following thing:

```
~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs
```

edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/freefilesync-ffs-*.list` to look like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main
```

and, at last, install the previous release package:

```
~$ sudo apt-get clean all
~$ sudo apt-get update
~$ sudo apt-get install freefilesync
```

---

**Note:** I tested these instructions installing the `precise` package over the `trusty` release, not on your system.

Comment: Well, on my system it needs more libraries (like libwxbase3.0-0 and libwxgtk3.0-0), which, as it told, could not be installed. Anyhow, thanks for your efforts.